# React props not passing correctly

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass an id value (listId) from my store as props to my Component without any success. I think the problem is that the id is generated by the addList action, which is dispatched first, followed by the addTrack action. Neither `listId={props.listId}` or something like `listId={props.listId ? props.listId : 1234}` seem to work. Here is my code:

```
const MakeList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Make a list </h1>
      <ListForm
        listId={props.listId}
        onSubmit={(item) => {
          props.dispatch(addList(item));
        }}
        trackSubmit={(item) => {
          props.dispatch(addTrack(item, props.listId));
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    listId: state.userLists.listIdArray[index],
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MakeList);
```

Comment: try console logging props.listId in your MakeList and reproduce here so that we can help you out

Comment: It looks like you trying to get value that does not exist at the time you try to get it from redux. Maybe if you explain what you try to accomplish it would be easier to find a proper solution

Comment: in your mapStateToProps where are getting your `index` from ?

Comment: @ aravind_reddy If I console log the listId from the trackSubmit function I get the value I need, It is just not getting passed on the listId prop

Comment: @lomboboo Yes that is the case. I do get the value after onSubmit though but the listId prop doesn't seem to update. I am making music lists that have 10 tracks. I need to pass the id from every list as listId on every track so I know to which list each track belongs to. I can pass it fine from addTrack dispatch but I need to use it on my main ListForm component, thats why I am trying to pass it from the listId prop.

Comment: @aravind_reddy I skipped that part from my code sorry. I have a global index which I increment on onSubmit, `index != 0 && index++`

Comment: Does `listIdArray` exist on initial load in redux? Print output of the state inside `mapStateToProps`

Comment: @lomboboo This is the state after a list is created. Might be hard to read from here. `{listIdArray: Array(1), listById: {…}}
listById
:
5cfc7473-7bed-428e-8fbd-3e8c69c16410
:
id
:
"5cfc7473-7bed-428e-8fbd-3e8c69c16410"
listAuthor
:
"author"
listTitle
:
"list"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
listIdArray
:
Array(1)
0
:
"5cfc7473-7bed-428e-8fbd-3e8c69c16410"
length
:
1`

Comment: Also provide your ListForm code so that we can trace the issue with the code

Comment: @aravind_reddy I don't think the problem has anything to do with listForm, I can pass dummy props fine to ListForm. When I do this `{props.listId ? props.listId : 1234}` I just get 1234 on ListForm

Comment: @slwjc I asked output `state` inside `mapsStateToProps`, not after it's created

Comment: @lomboboo Do you mean my initial redux state? const `listReducerDefaultState = {
  listIdArray: [],
  listById: {},
  tracksById: {},
  index: ''
};`

Comment: @slwjc Maybe from another way - when do you add something inside `listIdArray`? Can you reproduce it on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: @lomboboo I add Id's to the `listIdArray` when the addList action is dispatched. So initially the `listId={props.listId}` doesn't have any value, until the addList happens. I am curious why am I not able to update it since I get the value fine from `trackSubmit`

Comment: That is probably because `trackSubmit` happens after you dispatch `addList`

Comment: @lomboboo Yeap, but why can't I assign the value from inside trackSubmit for example? I tried having a global listId and assign the value but this doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you dispatch it wrong. Are you sure listIdArray gets updated after addList happens? Debug what happens with the redux extension from Chrome dev tools. It's really hard to help when you provide only component code. Can you create simple demo on jsfiddle that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @lomboboo I will try to make a simple demo. Yes, the listIdArray gets updated as soon as the addList happens. Its all about the `listId` prop that is not getting updated when I try to pass it that value

Comment: @slwjc provide a jsfiddle or sandbox demo so that we can debug it